# List files that do not begin with a specific prefix

Tags: ls, wildcards

I need to list only the files in a directory that do NOT begin with `qc_dl`, `qc_dt` or `qd_df`, but that also DO end in `.sas`.

I can list the files that do not begin with "qc_dl" as such:

```
ls -I "qc_dl*"
```

But then I do not know how to only select the SAS programs from the resultant list.

Furthermore, I can select all SAS files that begin either with "qc_dl", "qc_dt" or "qd_df", as follows:

```
ls qc_d{l,t,f}*.sas
```

However, I cannot combine the two commands to only list SAS files that DO NOT begin with `qc_dl/t/f`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Comment: This didn't show me how to filter on files with a common ending (ie. .sas)

Comment: See: http://imgur.com/EYMTpqx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming file names don't contain newline characters and don't start with `.`, this should work:

```
ls -d -- *.sas | grep -v '^qc_d[ltf]'
```

List files ending in .sas and filtering all that is NOT qc_dl, qc_dt, qc_df

For any filtering needs, grep is your friend.

Answer (score 14):

Use `find` instead?

```
find /my/example/dir -type f -name '*.sas' ! -name 'qc_d[ltf]*'
```

Answer (score 12):

From man bash:

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ```
>          ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

You can then use more powerful pattern matching when this is enabled.

To turn it on:

```
~$ shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can list files that end with `.sas` and do not begin with `qc_d`:

```
~$ ls
a.sas  a.txt  b.sas  b.txt  c.sas  c.txt  qc_dc.sas  qc_df.sas  qc_dl.sas  qc_dt.sas
~$ ls !(qc_d*).sas
a.sas  b.sas  c.sas
```

To turn it off:

```
~$ shopt -u extglob
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I combined qc_d[ltf] to get all three options, because there are some qc_d*.sas programs that I need, eg. qc_demo.sas.
So final command was:
> ls !(qc_d[ltf]*).sas

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -d [![.qc_dl.][.qc_dt.][.qd_df.]]*.sas

reference "man 7 glob"
[!...] -> any thing but not in that class equivalent to [^...] in grep or regex
[.qc_dl.] -> accurate pattern to mach exactly "qc_dl" inside 
class rather than any character or range occurrence  

scenario: hey mr shell please list for me all things not starting
in "qc_dl" nor "qc_dt" nor "qd_df"  but if any of them ending
with .sas then its ok you can list them. 

experiment:
$ touch qc_dloooooooo.sas
$ touch qc_dloooooooo
$ touch qc_dtfffghhjh.sas
$ touch qc_dtfffghhjh
$ touch cvvvbkkk
$ touch cvvvbxcvvcxv
$ ls -d [![.qc_dl.][.qc_dt.][.qd_df.]]*.sas
qc_dloooooooo.sas  qc_dtfffghhjh.sas
```